# box-sizing: border-box; doesn't affect textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, box-sizing

I searched for a way to size a `textarea` according to the rest of my layout and stumbled over the box-sizing method. I probably didn't use it correctly because it doesn't work for me. I have a layout that shows 3 different rows. The middle row should display a text-input field and below are all the recent posts. Now i want the `textarea` to be the same width as my other postings.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <!-- Empty Space -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <textarea placeholder="Text here"></textarea>
    <div class="well"> Posts ...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <!-- Empty Space -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
textarea{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Your posts will automatically take up all the space in the column because `div`s are block-level elements. See my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthiastotschnig/romqhvr5/).

As a side note, the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property just defines the relation between specified width/height and computed width/height.

Comment: @Lukas Sure thing! If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute width to the `textarea` css

Like this:

```
width:100px; // you can change it to whatever width you want
```

```css
textarea{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    resize: none;
    width:100px; /* set you own width */

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <!-- Empty Space -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            Some text here
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <textarea placeholder="Text here"></textarea> 
           <div class="well"> Posts ...</div>



        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
            Some text here
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <!-- Empty Space -->
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what i was asking for. The textarea should be the same WIDTH as the other items in that row

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
  outline: none;
}
```

That should remove the glow witch resizes your textarea.